# secure photos on server

Tags: javascript, security, asp.net-mvc, cryptography

I would like to hear advice from the more experienced developers. The project is now in the design stage. It's mobile application and a simple web application. Content is pictures, comments, personal correspondence.

Pictures can be quite personal. Need a very serious attitude to security.

The question is simple: **where to store photos and how to secure it?**

I think it's will be in the following way:
1. User make some photo. Via SSL the application sends photo to the server.
2. The server recieve photo, encrypt it and store somewhere.

Also, via app the user can see all own photos.
1. Request to server for photos.
2. Server decrypt stored photos and send via SSL to client.

I need some technical advices: where to save images, I know that database is quite slow for this case, which algorithms use for encrypt/decrypt, what about cache. It will be highload project and performance is very important.

Mobile application is planned on cross-platform framework like phoneGap, Titanium. On the server is .NET. But it is planned. I also consider full stack frameworks for javascript.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the primary question is how to secure the photos when they are on your server, correct?  You may want to edit the question to focus solely on that.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: yes, it's primary question.

Comment: Its an interesting question.  And your English is excellent.

Comment: **Unclear what help you need.** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Amazon S3.

They have a pretty decent API for .net and I use it for all my image storage.

You can set privacy on an image "bucket" which means without accessing with the user/password or token they will be perfectly secure.

Also of course, you get all the cloud rednundancy and location based hosted services, also would be great if you are going to be using it with mobile and web, as you won't be restricted by having your images stuck on a web server.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

Comment: Yes, I consider such variant. But, for some people have opinion that the clouds is not safe (trust). Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user348173 - So encrypt the data and decrypt it using the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

*where to save images*

Like you realised, saving images onto a database isn't worthwhile for your purpose. The usual approach is to -

1. **Save the uploaded image into any directory** on the server.
2. And then **save the path to the image in the database**.

Since you are encrypting the images too, it shouldn't matter if somebody figures out where the images are on the server. (Ofcourse, you need to make sure your crypto keys are safe but that's another topic.)

Answer (score 1):

In project I'm working currently on I had to solve same problem.

My solution is :

- Store resources on HDD as files (HDD is made for this task so this is the best solution imho).
- Store in database id's of resources with path's and additional 'meta data'.
- To provide client (iPad in this case) with secured photos we are using Spring MVC with Basic Authentication and REST interface.

Basic auth over HTTPS satisfies authentication requirement. You can easily implement it with Spring. Spring also provides you with REST interface for HTTP requests. Files should be stored on hard disk. Additional meta data can be stored in database to provide fast searching (f.e upload date or upload user).

It can be easily implemented with tools I've mentioned. That's why I think it's good solution. There are also many content repositories which can be installed on server where webapp will be deployed. I considered using Jackrabbit but solution I've provdied satisfied our needs.

Comment: "don't know any .NET frameworks" -- are you aware about [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/overview.html)?

Comment: I thought Spring is only dedicated to the Java. I'm suprised.

Answer (score 0):

That won't be a long answer but maybe it helps.

How about storing it on Azure, AWS, Google or Manta. Then you encrypt the data with a secure algorithm by using the device IMEI.

As storage I would prefere Azure, I use it on my own atm and is very nice for .net and node.js.

As algortihm how about Rijndael or RSA.

A bit more explanation, the IMEI is unique and so nobody else can decrypt it, without access to the device. The other stuff, the cloud is the only option for global access.

Comment: would you mind explaining in more details why do you recommend this solution?

Comment: @gnat what do you mean? What is missing?

Comment: as far as I can tell, this answer lacks an explanation on how recommended solution is going to serve needs laid out in the question

Comment: As far as I understood, he wanted suggestions for storage, encryption and security. So why is explanation missing?

Answer (score -1):

It may be not a good idea to use javascript to decrypt, if so, every one that have access to your site, will have a copy of the decryptor,
the solution I can suggest is to keep photos encrypted at database. decryption must be on the server side when a secure request come through an ssl connection.
I don't sure but maybe blocking direct links to photos is also useful, your links must be come through a secure routing

Comment: And what about unique decryption keys? How would thief get those?

Comment: Please correct if I am wrong; when you have an script on the client side to decrypt an encrypted file or any thing, you give a clue about what encryption method is taken, what is decryptor key length, and any other thing that needed to decrypt an encrypted file; so one thing remain is to find is the key, and you also send one copy to client in each request...

Comment: If you generate a key clientside and encrypt/decrypt photos with it using a well known algorithm like AES and store the encrypted data on the server, an attacker isn't going to be able to do anything without the key. Hiding the algorithm is security through obscurity, which is a bad idea.